# Stack overflow mirror "whyfaq"

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

Surely [this](http://rads.whyfaq.com/questions/1807906/how-was-a-url-like-http-stackoverflow-com-posts-1807421-edit-created-in-php) (rads.whyfaq.com) isn't an official stackexchange domain?

Does this meet the attribution policy? It links to user profiles, they just happen to be hosted on the wrong domain.

Comment: That doesn't look like a proper mirror. In fact, a lot of the links on there are broken.